# Obtaining an extra boss token

Tags: spiral-knights

Now, in Spiral Knights, fighting your way through a set of boss levels will normally give you three boss tokens as a reward for your hard work. However, occasionally the system will decide to be generous and give you 4 tokens instead. Considering running boss levels isn't exactly a quick thing, I'd like to obtain this 4-token reward as much as possible, except I can't figure out what triggers it. So, does anyone have any idea how to ensure you gain 4 tokens from the boss level?

**Things I know do NOT determine it:**

1)Running the boss solo (I do this all the time)

2)Completing the entire level set without dying (I've done this and not gotten 4 tokens, and the last time I got 4 tokens I had to revive once.)

3)Doing the boss levels via the clockworks rather than the mission screen (As far as I can tell, it makes no difference, aside from the initial 1-token bonus you get when you clear the relative mission for the first time.)

Comment: Whatever the trigger, I've never got 4 tokens from single run, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The 4th token seems to be random.**

I have yet to find official word on this matter, but multiple users have [documented experiences](http://forums.spiralknights.com/en/node/32989#comment-198708) which indicate that:

- Walking through the token before it falls = 0 tokens
- Completing 1 depth and the boss = 1 token
- Completing 2 depths and the boss = 2 tokens
- Completing 3 depths and the boss = 3 tokens
- There is a random chance to get an additional token no matter where you join.

Comment: I've also got 1 token for doing all levels except 1, and once I got 3 tokens for only doing one level.... And if you walk through the token too soon and don't get any, you can just walk back to it and you'll get them.  :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as most have been able to determine, it is simply random.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely random. I think it's a 65% chance for 3, a 25% chance for 4, and 10% for 5.

Comment: Do you have a source on this, or is it just conjecture?

Comment: "Completely random" would mean that there is no percentage based chance. I would assume conjecture, as such.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends what level u join in.
Depth 1 = 1
Depth 2 = 2
Depth 3 = 3

But if you escaped the mission and joining back again you get 1 or 2.